# Joomla configuration.php unwritable when permission is 0644 but writable when 0664

Tags: joomla, permissions

My Joomla is 3.9.4, when I try to make some global configuration change on back-end, I got this error: Could not write to the configuration file.
I looked at the file system, configuration.php has the right owner and is set to 0644, actually I can make change to it via FTP.

I then try settiong the permission to 0777, it is writable; then I try 0666 and 0664, it is also good. Only when I set it to 0644, I get the above error. I've never encountered this kind of problem before. What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check PHP Ownership. PHP code can be executed not using the same user ID like using FTP. You can set your web server to run PHP as CGI to ensures that PHP is executed using the same user.